# How to find all strings in a list that are matching a specific structure?

Tags: java, string

I am running into this problem in Java.
I want to find in a string list all the strings matching the structure 
composed as follows:

ex:

"?ea?ch" where "?" can be any character and can be anywhere in the string.

I have tried using .contains but i don't know what should i do to match all the characters for "?"

Should I make a loop and replace the "?" with every available character and search the list, or is there a better way to do this? 
Thank you!

Comment: Are you allowed to use regex?

Comment: That's what [`regular expressions`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) are for.

Comment: @PM77-1 Can you search through lists with regexes? Or would you still have to loop through all the strings, but just use regex to match?

Comment: OK, I think I understand, I will use :( . Any character (may or may not match line terminators) instead of "?", Thank you!

Comment: @PM77-1 I have a HashMap<String,String> structure and I have to search all the matching keys.

Comment: Are you already on Java 8? If so, you can use a combination of `filter` (using regex) and `findFirst`.

Comment: @PM77-1 Yes I am using Java 8, Thank you, I will try this!

Answer (score 1):

Code:

```
    List<String> strings = Arrays.asList(
            "test123",
            "1ea1ch",
            "dazch",
            "6ea5ch");

    strings.stream().filter(s -> s.matches(".ea.ch")).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

> 1ea1ch
>
> 6ea5ch